# multiply quantity by time - how do you calculate 15 times 30mins?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to calculate time tracking.

I have days split out by 30 mins intervals, and project activity against each 30 mins slot, however how do I add the 30 mins intervals for each project entry?

e.g. I have 11 entries for one project, so 11 slots each of 30 mins, how do I calculate this as time interval?

Comment: By "in time" do you mean something that looks like "5 hours 30 mins" rather than just "330 mins"?

Comment: In order to better understand your needs, can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 2):

What do you exactly mean?

1/ use a mod 60 to calculate the minutes, and an int div for the hours.
(n * 30 DIV 60) for the hours, 
(n * 30 MOD 60) for the minutes.

For instance, 11 * 30 DIV 60 -> 5
11 * 30 mod 60 -> 30

Result will be 5 : 30 for 11 slots of 30mn.

2/ is it in an app ? Which one ? If in excel, the MOD and DIV functions exists. If in bash or other scripting language, the operator % is often used to do a modulo.

[With Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUPc5.jpg)

[With Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNMjn.jpg)

(cannot post images directly)

Comment: Welcome to Super user,, please [edit] your post, and to make your post meaningful, share some data along with the results the formula you have used has generated so far !!

Comment: Share some screen shot !

Comment: I need 10 points :)

Comment: upvoted to give you 10 points. welcome to SU

Answer (score 2):

If you subtract two of the existing intervals you should get a format that you can multiply to return the appropriate result. If you are using a format like hh:mm:ss then simply multiply 00:30:00 by 11 should return 5:30:00.
If you want that to return 5.5 then use =hour(A1) + Minute(A1)/60 (assuming the 5:30 is in A1). For minutes use =hour(A1) * 60 + Minute(A1).

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to create Table comprises 11 project entries and along side the time interval considering gap of 30 minutes,, you have calculated something different !

Comment: thank you this works